# Laravel Eloquent Pagination, how to count before pagination with filters?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here my code :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility','conciergeries.network')
            ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
                $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
            })  
            ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
                $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
            })
            ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($searchFiliale) {
                $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchFiliale/i");
            })
                ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
                ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
                ->simplePaginate(50);

        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];

        return $res;
```

Hi, actually i get all "Prestation" items at 'total', but i need the real total just before the `simplePaginate(50);` after all of my conditions.
How i can give this value at 'total' without disturbing my code ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent queries are very flexible and you can store them as variables before executing them.

Here is a simplified example of what you could do:

```
// Start your query and store it as a variable
$query = Prestation::where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i");

// Now count the total number of entries which will return
$count = $query->count();

// Finally, do your pagination
$prestations = $query->simplePaginate(50);
```

Of course you can add all of your other constraints to the query, i've just removed them to simplify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
 $prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility','conciergeries.network')
                ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
                    $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
                })  
                ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
                    $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
                })
                ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($searchFiliale) {
                    $query->select('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchFiliale/i");
                })
                    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
                    ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection);

            $res = [
                'results' => $prestations->simplePaginate(50),
                'total' => $prestations->count(),
            ];

            return $res;
```